# Get unique identifier of a system (not the MAC-address)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, uuid

for some reasons I need to get a unique identifier of a Linux system that does not change when the system is rebooted (but may change when the user replaces nameable amounts of the hardware or formats harddisk).

Following solutions are **NOT** possible:

- use the MAC-address (this is already used but fails on some systems
  because there is no network interface)
- use blkid to get the UUID of a    partition - this command is not
  available on all systems and it is a    bit difficult to
  automatically find out which partition to use for    that

So...any other idea how a system could be identified uniquely?

Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/) may be helpful. Especially hdparm seems valid for me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus  Good luck...

Comment: May I ask what do you need this for? Perhaps there is some other solution that does not need such an unique identifier.

Comment: Disk drives have a serial number as do mother boards. However mother board serial numbers are not really dependable unless it is equipment manufactured for particular devices. many web servers use the HTTP request header information provided by the browser as a kind of probability based identifier so it may be possible to use a variety of inputs to generate an identifier.  Are there any constraints on the format for the identifier?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to combine info from multiple sources.  Also, the MAC is worthless bad because it can *easily* be spoofed in Linux by anyone with admin/root/sudo permission.   `dmidecode` is probably the best bet in general, because it contains info that can only be modified by replacing the mobo and/or CPU.  At which point, I would argue it's a different system.

Comment: You could use the CPU ID. Have a look here:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144812/generate-consistent-machine-unique-id

Comment: You should use the cpu id and/or the motherboard id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to your question will depend on what you consider to be a "permanent" part of the system.  Let's assume you decide that the hard drive partitions are semi-permanent from your applications perspective, then calculate some sort of hash of the contents of `/proc/paritions`.

In bash, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /proc/partitions |sha1sum|cut "-d " -f1
```

Comment: Using `#!/bin/sh` instead will be more portable and probably faster (for example, in Debian it uses the faster Dash shell). There is usually no reason to use Bash for scripting IMO.